# Implementing treeview on datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have dynamic treeview using datatable that get needed information from database.

Now i am trying to add 2 columns to treeview and then i understood that treeview must be on datagrid column.

So i searched a lot and confused.

I am using below code block to generate my treeview and it works like a charm;

```
foreach (DataRow rows in folders.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(rows["PARENTID"]) == parentID)
                {
                    String key = rows["ID"].ToString();
                    String text = rows["title"].ToString();
                    TreeNodeCollection newParentNode = parentNode.Add(key, text).Nodes;
                    PopulateTreeView(newParentNode, Convert.ToInt32(rows["ID"]), folders);
                }
            }
```

However as i stated i need to add 2 more columns using datagrid.

I know there is a bunch of control on the internet but they all are too old and not working with my above code.

Which way should i follow to create my own treeviewgrid ?

Comment: I know this is very likely not feasible but switching to WPF instead of WinForms would make this way easier.

Comment: @Filburt i already almost finish my project and i don't really know how diffucult switching whole project to wpf. Actually i have only 6 pages but....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two more columns in your DataRow object, you could do a couple of things:

1. You could simply append the additional column's data to the text of the TreeNode.

   `text += $"\t{rows["extraColumn1"].ToString()}\t{rows["extraColumn2"].ToString()}";`
2. You could add the extra columns to a tool tip.  This would require that you add a ToolTip control to the form (named for example toolTip1), and then update the `ToolTip on toolTip1` property when the mouse moves over a node.  A little bit of work, and you would also want to keep a reference to the two columns of data that you would populate the tool tip with.  A quick way to do that would be to set the rows object to the Tag property of the TreeNode.
3. You could create your own extension of the TreeView control that has two more fields that it could display.  This would be quite a bit of work.